# Bash in PHP: Command line substitution: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: php, bash, shell

I am extracting information from proftpd logs. I have to call this one-liner from a PHP script but it does not work anymore from there.

This is the original line, which works:

```
(gunzip -c xferlog*.gz; cat xferlog?(*)!(.gz)) | grep 'host [0-9]\+ file a _ o r ftpuser' | sort -k 5n,5 -k 2M,2 -k 3n,3 -k 4,4 | tail -1 | cut -c 1-24
```

This is the error I got when executed in PHP:

```
$cmd = "(gunzip -c $logFile*.gz; cat $logFile?(*)!(.gz)) | grep '$host [0-9]\+ $file a _ o r $ftpUser' | sort -k 5n,5 -k 2M,2 -k 3n,3 -k 4,4 | tail -1 | cut -c 1-24";
exec($cmd);
sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I tried several bash scripts that would be called by PHP, but it has not been successful. I had errors like:

```
bash: command substitution: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: command substitution: line 9: `cat ${LOGS}?(*)!(.gz)'
```

or

```
bash: ./extract_date_in_xferlog.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: ./extract_date_in_xferlog.sh: line 8: `(gunzip -c ${LOGS}*.gz; cat ${LOGS}?(*)!(.gz)) | grep "$HOST [0-9]\+ $FILE a _ o r $USER" | sort -k 5n,5 -k 2M,2 -k 3n,3 -k 4,4 | tail -1 | cut -c 1-24'
```

I am a bit confused, thank you for your help!

Comment: Please post the PHP `exec()` call. We need to see how you're quoting it.

Comment: Well, not using `?(*)!(.gz)` makes it work. It does not answer my question, but at least now it works with: `(gunzip -c $logFile*.gz 2>&1 ; cat $logFile $logFile.[0-9] 2>&1 )...`

Answer (score 1):

The weird wildcard uses extended globbing. You need to enable extglob either as part of your script (probably better) or in your Bash setup (probably where it was before, and then it broke when somebody changed it for unrelated reasons).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not escaping the quotes correctly in the script.

I suggest handling the shell command as a single quoted string assuming you don't want to embed PHP variables in the shell command, and then making sure that all the single quotes in the command are escaped with `\'` to avoid prematurely terminating the PHP string.

Alternatively you could use a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [NOWDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) style string to avoid escaping issues.

Comment: Well, I tried this: CT=`cat "${LOGS}?(*)!(.gz)"` it returned this: `cat: /var/log/proftpd/xferlog?(*)!(.gz): No such file or directory`. However, my first goal would have to have it work in PHP.

Comment: I don't get it because if I quote the wildcards are not considered as wildcards anymore. When I `gunzip -c xferlog*.gz`, doing `gunzip -c 'xferlog*.gz'` or `gunzip "xferlog*.gz"` fails. Is there another way in bash scripting to quote but keep the wildcards?